# How do I Forward root's email to an external email address?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I have a small server (Ubuntu 10.04) at my house and I would like to forward `root`'s email to my gmail hosted domain to get security notifications and what not.

I ripped everything out and started from scratch and ran into some [other issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/215388/).

I now have sendmail working in the sense that I can `mail some@external.com` and get the mail.

HOWEVER, adding an address to `/root/.forward` does not actually forward the message.  I get the following in my logs:

```
Dec 22 14:04:37 batcave sendmail[4695]: 
       oBML4bAT004695: to=<root@batcave>, ctladdr=aburns (1000/1000), 
       delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30075, 
       relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (oBML4bJ9004696 
       Message accepted for delivery)
Dec 22 14:04:39 batcave sm-mta[4698]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[69.145.248.18],
       version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DES-CBC3-SHA, bits=168/168
Dec 22 14:04:40 batcave sm-mta[4698]: oBML4bJ9004696: to=<root@batcave.net>,
       ctladdr=<aburns@bresnan.net> (1000/1000), delay=00:00:03, xdelay=00:00:03,
       mailer=relay, pri=120336, relay=[69.145.248.18] [69.145.248.18], 
       dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 01/D4-00853-216621D4)
```

You can see where my local sendmail instance accepts it then hands it off to my ISP, but with the wrong address (root@batcave.net).

Comment: Not sure what changed, but it started working later that day with /root/.forward

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of using `/root/.forward`, have you tried putting

```
root: me@batcavern.com
```

into `/etc/aliases`?

(Note that you need to run `newaliases` after updating the `aliases` file.)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason is reverse DNS: does the IP of your box have an RR DNS entry?  Doing a forward lookup on the host shown in the logs (assuming you didn't modify) gives:

```
[root@ryor:~] dig batcave.batcavern.com

; <<>> DiG 9.3.4-P1.1 <<>> batcave.batcavern.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 7005
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;batcave.batcavern.com.         IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
batcavern.com.          3600    IN      SOA     ns1.sitelutions.com. erebusbat.batcavern.com. 54 28000 7200 604800 5

;; Query time: 503 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Nov 29 22:02:30 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 101

[root@ryor:~]
```

So it looks as if it doesn't even have an A record.  An SMTP host hoping to deliver mail and not be considered a spam relay needs to have both A and RR records.

Comment: No it does not have an A record because it is just a little home server.  Can I configure postfix to relay through my ISP/gmail?

Comment: Through your ISP - generally yes, quite easily.  Take a look at the *main.cf* variable `relayhost` (http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost).

Comment: Dare I say postfix is easier to configure for this as all you need to so is define the destination for 'root' in the /etc/postfix/aliases or /etc/aliases file.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a dynamic IP, check out dyndns.com.  It'll let you get an A record for your domain that'll update to match your IP.

Comment: I appreciate the answer Tex; however the domain (batcavern.com) already exists and has other servers.  Also I believe that email uses reverse DNS which I won't have for this box (it is at home on my cable modem).

Comment: Would it be possible to add an SPF record for your DNS? It's not quite reverse DNS...but it does help imply that the mail server is authenticated in some way (compared to just a regular IP range for a home network IP.

http://www.openspf.org/

I know these used to help pass messages through some methods of spam filtering